# maya.parse fails on certain dates (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace')

Tags: python, python-3.x

maya.parse function throws an error when attempting to parse certain ISO string dates.

Example:

`maya.parse("Mon, 02 Mar 2020 00:00:00 GMT")`

Working Examples:

`maya.parse("Wed, 02 Sep 2020 00:00:00 GMT")`
`<MayaDT epoch=1599004800.0>`

`maya.parse("Tue, 01 Sep 2020 00:00:00 GMT")`
`<MayaDT epoch=1598918400.0>`

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/eanna/.local/share/virtualenvs/yo-_4WEwAWG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/maya/core.py", line 766, in parse
    dt = pendulum.parse(str(string), **options)
  File "/Users/eanna/.local/share/virtualenvs/yo-_4WEwAWG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pendulum/parser.py", line 29, in parse
    return _parse(text, **options)
  File "/Users/eanna/.local/share/virtualenvs/yo-_4WEwAWG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pendulum/parser.py", line 56, in _parse
    tz=parsed.tzinfo or options.get("tz", UTC),
  File "/Users/eanna/.local/share/virtualenvs/yo-_4WEwAWG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pendulum/__init__.py", line 111, in datetime
    tz = _safe_timezone(tz)
  File "/Users/eanna/.local/share/virtualenvs/yo-_4WEwAWG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pendulum/__init__.py", line 82, in _safe_timezone
    elif obj.tzname(None) == "UTC":
  File "/Users/eanna/.local/share/virtualenvs/yo-_4WEwAWG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 238, in tzname
    return self._tznames[self._isdst(dt)]
  File "/Users/eanna/.local/share/virtualenvs/yo-_4WEwAWG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 291, in _isdst
    dstval = self._naive_is_dst(dt)
  File "/Users/eanna/.local/share/virtualenvs/yo-_4WEwAWG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 259, in _naive_is_dst
    timestamp = _datetime_to_timestamp(dt)
  File "/Users/eanna/.local/share/virtualenvs/yo-_4WEwAWG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 1814, in _datetime_to_timestamp
    return (dt.replace(tzinfo=None) - EPOCH).total_seconds()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

**Environment and Version**

- OS (incl. terminal and shell used): Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6
- Python Version: 3.7
- maya Version: 0.6.1
- Your timezone: British Summer Time